# Separation by semicolon instead of comma in biblatex' \cites

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

I am using `biblatex`+`biber` for the bibliography of my thesis. I use the `numeric-comp` citation style. Overall this works perfectly.

I generally use `\cite` to cite references; but occassionally also `\cites`, namely when I want to cite references in a specific (non-numeric) order, or when I want to specify page numbers for some (but not all) cited references using postnotes (i.e. between `[]`).

My question is about the latter usage of `\cites`, for example:

```
\cites[pp.173--199]{SomeBook}{SomePaper}
```

Which produces (10=SomeBook; 20=SomePaper):

```
[10, pp.173–199, 20]
```

I find the commas slightly confusing here. Therefore I was wondering if it is possible to somehow tell `biblatex` to use another separator, say a semicolon. So that I would get:

```
[10, pp.173–199; 20]
```

However, I do *not* want to replace commas with semicolons everywhere, only in this specific case. So all uses of `\cite`, and uses of `\cites` without postnotes, should still use commas.

If necessary I would be ok with a solution based on a separate command for the specific case. For example a `\semicites` command that uses a differently configured `\cites` internally.

**EDIT 2**
I changed my mind and went with a solution based on Marco's answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all I want to recommend the documentation of [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Next to the documenation the file `biblatex.def` is very useful for every user. There you can find every default definition of userdefined commands.

You are looking for the command `\multicitedelim`. The default setting in version 1.7 is a semicolon:

```
\newcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

The style `numeric` redefines the multicitedelim in the file `numeric.cbx`.

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

To set the default setting simple use:

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I apply this without changing a commas to semicolons? (cf. my question)

Comment: @Matthias It would be rather inconsistent to use different punctuations for the same situation.

Comment: Maybe, yet it is what I had in mind and explained above.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}`?

Comment: @lockstep: Typical copy-paste ;-)

Comment: Got this error `! LaTeX Error: Command \multicitedelim already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

Answer (score 2):

For my thesis (`phys` style) I now went with your original request. I define a new multicite command `\semicites`:

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\semicites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\cite}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

which gives me an output like `[280–282; 6, S. 88]` while leaving all other multicites intact, e.g. `[12, 15, 20]`.

As the former case appears very few times—at the moment once `:)`—I decided to have this inconsistency, but keep the commas for almost all citations, as that looks better to me (maybe I'm only used to it).